# Best type to use in a composite key when one of the values varies in type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, unique-constraint

I am building a data store for the content of multiple blog sites which have been scraped.  Each of these sites is going to have an entry in a `Blog` table

```
BlogId                  Url                         Version
int, PK, identity       varchar(2500), not null     int, not null
-----------------       -----------------------     -------------
                1       'http://site1.com/                      1
                2       'http://site2.com/                      1
                3       'http://site2.com/                      2
```

Then there will be a `Post` table:

```
BlogId                Url                        PostId
int, FK, not null     varchar(2500) not null     ?
```

For most blogs that I'm looking at, I can easily discern a `PostId` value that is unique for them.

For *all* blogs, the `Url` will be unique for a `BlogId` value.  However, the `Url` is *frequently subject to change*.

However, there are a few blogs that I can't discern a good `PostId` value when scraping the HTML.  In those cases, I can get the `datetimeoffset` that a post was published on.  The accuracy of the publishing frequency is on the minute level.

The question is, I need to build a composite natural key (I won't use it as a primary key because I'll need to relate to other tables and don't want to carry this along to those tables) using the `BlogId` and the `PostId` but I'm not sure what I should type the `PostId` as.  I've been thinking of two options:

- `sql_variant` - I could use an `int` for most of my sites, and that would be fine and then use `datetimeoffset` for the ones where I can't easily discern a unique numeric `PostId`
- `bigint` - The `PostId` would fit in here and I can encode the `datetimeoffset` as a `bigint` (`2011-11-11 13:59` would become `201111111359`)
- Or some other approach I haven't thought about.

Some other key facts:

- The `Post` table will only have a few thousand records in it initially (if there are more than five thousand, I'd be surprized)
- There are related tables for tags, categories, etc, which will be joined with this table (maybe a few thousand records at most)
- The growth of any of these tables won't be astronomical.  *Maybe* a another five thousand records a year (that's being conservative on my part but you never know)
- This key will only be used to create an index/constraint, currently, I don't foresee the use of it in queries (there are other attributes that I am linking to which are of more concern).

Comment: So all you want to do is enforce uniqueness?

Comment: @JackDouglas: Yes; there might be some mining of these tables later for data, but this composite key will not be a part of that (it will be related to other data on other attributes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't even consider forcing data of different types into one field.

Another option:

- synthetic post_id and
- child tables for each 'type' of 'native_post_id'

There are various ways to go about [enforcing the subset relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522320/what-is-the-best-way-to-enforce-a-subset-relationship-with-integrity-constrain/5522344#5522344) between these child tables and the parent if necessary

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good route for me; the goal of the structure is to be flexible enough to accommodate different ways that namespaces/domains identify their content.  From what I can tell by the linked answer I have to have a table per data type I want to use as the natural key in the domain; what does this gain me except for many extra tables when a `sql_variant` does the same job?  I've updated my question to reflect this (last item in the "other key facts setion").

Comment: IMO you will end up regretting it. If you don't want/need extra tables then a bunch of extra columns and perhaps a functional index would be far preferable

Comment: I can appreciate the possibility of regretting it, but I can't understand it when the statement is so vague.  Would you elaborate on *why*?  What will a `sql_variant` as part of the key (given the updated information) do to post a problem?

Comment: eg ["sql_variant columns cannot be used in a computed column", "A sql_variant data type must first be cast to its base data type value before participating in operations"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx),

Comment: Both of which are not issues which I'm constrained on.  I appreciate future-proofing, and I can't say this will *never* be a condition, but at the same time, I'm fairly confident for what I'm trying to do, this will not be an issue ever, or for a long, long time.

Comment: sure - both intended to be example of the *kind* of problems rather than things that might specifically matter to you right now. Really though there is an inherent problem stuffing different type in one column - it is not what RDBMSs are designed to do. 2 columns is simpler in every conceivable way.

Comment: do join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-clustered-index) if you want a second opinion...

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your intended use of the PostId.  Presumably it is going to be used like a query string (or MVC-style friendly URL suffix) to retrieve or link to the original post on its home site?

If the PostId value is only ever going to be used as a string, i.e. in the context of supplying a URI made up of the concatenation of URL + PostId, then you might just as well save it as a string, because that is the only context in which you are going to use it.

Since this is just a natural key and not your primary key, as you stated, this should do the job without being too *elegant*.

If, on the other hand, you mean to do some other kind of processing on PostId (other than string concatenation) then you probably ought not to save PostId as a string, unless you keep some kind of partitioning attribute that tells you which internal function you need to run the string through to get a type safe value.  If you are going to that much trouble, you might just as well keep multiple PostId *X* columns of various types to meet your needs.

Comment: The `PostId` is going to be used to uniquely identify a post within a namespace/domain, there will be a synthetic id generated as the primary key, this will be used for constraint/indexing purposes.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect the non-query use of the key.  It's not going to be used for anything really beyond the constraint.

Comment: If the constraint you're talking about is a unique constraint, built on the combination of BlogId and PostId, then using a string representation of PostId is likely to be as useful as any other representation - and probably a lot more convenient, since it will no doubt be coming to you over http as a string to begin with.