# Would elasticsearch or RavenDB be better for fueling a statistics engine/random forest?

Tags: nosql

(Note: this question [exists on StackOverflow as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137252/would-elasticsearch-or-ravendb-be-better-for-fueling-a-statistics-engine-random) but I thought it might have a better reception here.  If it proves this is the better place, I'll close/ask to migrate/link to this.  Also, if it *doesn't* really belong here, I'd be happy to delete it.)

I've been looking at the following [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) databases for the next phase of my project:

- [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)
- [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/)

elasticsearch positions itself as primarily serving advanced search scenarios while RavenDB positions itself as a document-oriented-database.

Primarily, the document will be around videos.  Each has a natural id.  That will be the key of the document.

Around that, I add other content in fields which will not necessarily be scalar or flat, as the information will come from a number of different sources with different structures.

For example, there will be content from the video provider's Atom feeds, [blog posts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7810/best-type-to-use-in-a-composite-key-when-one-of-the-values-varies-in-type) that have the video embedded in it, and other pieces of data from a [data warehouse project](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/179?m=2425738#2425738).

There is no set structure across all of the items (each of them will be very domain-specific, actually), the only thing that will relate them is the natural key of the video mentioned above.

That said, once I have this information in one of the above solutions, I'll want to do a number of things with it:

- Cull it to help populate variables in a [random forest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15076/determining-the-variables-when-training-a-classifying-with-a-random-forest) in order to make classifications about the videos
- Provide general search on the videos (general free-text, not based on the results of the random forest) through a web-based front end (ASP.NET MVC if you must know)

There are some requirements:

- I will more than likely be in a ASP.NET shared web hosting environment.  This means I'll have one machine, and won't have access to set up a service.  Something embeddable will be *very* helpful.
- The ASP.NET environment will be hosted in IIS, so the embeddable aspect will have to survive [app-domain recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564/what-exactly-is-appdomain-recycling).
- I'll want to create new indexes based on the results of the statistical analysis which I can easily fascet which will help with the search on the site.
- Support for autocomplete functionality (I know this isn't an "out-of-the box" request, but being able to get to that point is important).
- Rich synonym support (there's a number of them in the type of videos I'm indexing content around)

I'm also open to services, such as [Truffler](http://truffler.net/), although I do have concerns about the cost (and in Truffler's case, a little concerned about latency between the data centers, because the requests will come from the web host on the West coast, or from a back-end process on the East coast).

Additionally, I don't feel that *one* solution needs to fit *all* the requirements.  I'm more than fine with having one serve one purpose and having another serve another purpose.  Granted, [migrations suck](http://ayende.com/blog/4468/that-no-sql-thing-document-database-migrations), but migrating between these two document stores is a little easier (and I don't expect them to use the same document structure, necessarily).

Comment: Along the lines of elasticsearch and Truffler, there's also [IndexTank](http://indextank.com/) which reddit uses (with mixed success).

Answer (score 5):

Ravendb embedds quite nicely into a .net application and also allows you to create full text (embedded) lucene.net indexes. Given your constraints on the hosting elasticsearch won't be a viable option since you'll need it to run as a service alongside of your MVC application.

Lucene.net does not support facets out of the box but ravendb comes to the rescue here too:
http://ravendb.net/documentation/faceted-search

Ravendb also allows you to control your lucene.net analyzers quite nicely:
http://ravendb.net/documentation/how-indexes-work

Disclosure: I'm the author of the elasticsearch .net client NEST so if anyone would try to sell you Elasticsearch it be me :)